# Spring security test with user

Tags: spring

At https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

I see test example

```
mvc.perform(get("/admin").with(user("admin").password("pass")...
```

What imports I have to perform for using

user("admin")

and

password("pass")

Comment: It's already given in `docs`. Please ask some relevant questions where you actually stuck.

Answer (score -1):

ok, don't bother it is

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;
```